# How to drop rows from dataframe after checking split text membership in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is the head of a dataframe I have:

```
london.head()

    Location    Borough                         Post town
0   Abbey Wood  Bexley, Greenwich               LONDON
1   Acton       Ealing, Hammersmith and Fulham  LONDON
2   Addington   Croydon                         CROYDON
3   Addiscombe  Croydon                         CROYDON
4   Albany Park Bexley                          BEXLEY, SIDCUP
```

Which is a list of areas of London, scraped from Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_areas_of_London

Boroughs are comma separated, with some locations sitting in two boroughs.

I have a list of boroughs in East London, which I would like to filter the dataframe by.

```
east_lon = ['Tower Hamlets', 'Newham', 'Waltham Forest', 'Barking and Dagenham', 'Redbridge', 'Havering', 'Hackney']
```

I have attempted to do this with this nested for loop which checks for membership of the single borough, or one of the boroughs after being split, in the list.

```
for index, row in london.iterrows():
    for borough in row['Borough'].split():
        if borough or (borough + ',') not in east_lon:
           london.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

I am receiving the error that

> [0] not found in axis'

What am I doing incorrectly? Is there a more suitable way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is compare values by sets with [`isdisjoint`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_isdisjoint.asp), last for invert mask use `~`:

```
east_lon = ['Bexley', 'Ealing', 'Waltham Forest']

s = set(east_lon)
mask = df['Borough'].apply(lambda x: set(x.split(', ')).isdisjoint(s))

df = df[~mask]
print (df)
      Location                         Borough       Post town
0   Abbey Wood               Bexley, Greenwich          LONDON
1        Acton  Ealing, Hammersmith and Fulham          LONDON
4  Albany Park                          Bexley  BEXLEY, SIDCUP
```

Comment: golfed `df.Borough.str.split(', ').map({*east_lon}.isdisjoint)`

Comment: I love the use of `isdisjoint` very clever.

Comment: Great stuff. Works a charm

Answer (score 1):

Using `isin` and `any`

```
m=pd.DataFrame(df['Borough'].str.split(', ').tolist(),index=df.index).isin(east_lon).any(axis=1)

df=df[m].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help.

```
london = london[london['Borough'].str.contains('|'.join(east_lon))]
```

Comment: Here I suggest add some notes when solution working correctly - test values not splitted by `,`, but all values. so if `east_lon= ['aaa','bbb']` it return both `True` also for this sample data in column  - `london['Borough'] = ['aaa ddd,sss', 'bbb']` - first value is not tested `aaa ddd`, but only `aaa`. Depends of OP if need test values splitted by `,` or not.

Comment: True. I just assumed boroughs to be unique without common substrings. Thanks for mentioning.